# Logic signals have too high a voltage - Solved

Tags: digital-logic, pcb-design, circuit-design, signal-integrity

I am trying to control a 5 inch display from a Raspberry Pi Pico controller. I am using a display from BuyDisplay.com which uses the RA8875 driver chip and has an 8080 parallel interface (Note: BuyDisplay have changed their product line since I brought the display so one with the same pinout is not yet available - in any case there was no schematic supplied).

I am trying to write the driver (in Rust). I have done this in the past with other displays and found the rats nest of cables I had to connect was a source of unreliability in development. As such I decided to take the risk and design and get manufactured a PCB that:

- Has the Pico mounted,
- Has the power supply regulators,
- Has sockets for other peripherals
- Can be plugged directly into the back of the board.

Schematics (work in progress) and PCB (ground and power planes shown hatched) are:

[image: Controller Schematic MCU]
[image: Controller Schematic Display Connector]
[image: Controller Schematic Power]
[image: Controller Schematic Connectors]
[image: Controller PCB - Power planes hatched]

(also available as Kicad project at https://github.com/adoble/modular-audio/tree/main/hardware/controller)

After being unsuccessful in getting my code to drive the display, I had a more detailed look at the signals that were coming off the PCB (with hindsight, something I should have done before!). A typical signal for one of the data lines looked like:

[image: Data signal without termination]

There was a “ringing” on the edges and the voltage peaked to 4.08 V. I fear that I have fried the RA8875 drive chip!

Before buying another display, I tried adding on a “termination” circuit for each signal between where it “exits” the PCB and “enters”  the display board. The circuit looks like:

[image: Termination network]

I was assuming that the PCB  tracks were the culprit and also that they have an impedance of about 50 Ohm - hence the 47 Ohm resistor. The data signals now looked like this.

[image: Data signal with termination]

I’m thinking this looks reasonable with a Vmax of 3.6 V (but more about that later).

However, other signals look terrible, for instance the chip select (CS) looks like this:

[image: CS signal with termination]

So:

1. What can I do to get decent logic signals without high voltage peaks?
2. I also mentioned that the logic signals have a Vmax of 3.6 V. I would have expected 3.3V from the Pico. I don't understand where this is coming from and how I can change it?

Thanks for any help.

**Update**

I used the suggestion of @Justme and removed the termination and then measured the signal *with a ground coil*. Results for both the CS (yellow) and DATA0 (blue) signal are:

[image: CS signal without termination and measured using ground coil on probe]
[image: DATA0 signal without termination and measured using ground coil on probe]

These both look very good - it seems that my measuring technique was leaving me to the wrong conclusions.

Display still does not work, but I'm pretty confident now that this is a software problem.

Comment: Not a single bypass capacitor! Your skinny power supply tracks will have significant inductance and require capacitors at the point of load. Suggestion - fatten up your power supply tracks and sprinkle some 100nF caps around. I also assume you have a groundplane on the pcb that is not shown in the layout you posted?

Comment: It almost looks like the CS is an open drain output.  Could you check the data sheet to confirm, or not?

Comment: I would get rid of the 47 ohm/1 nF termination and put 22 ohm series resistors at the output of the driver (source termination).  Like what Justme suggested.

Comment: @Kartman I've been assuming that the Pico board has enough decoupling capacitors on it. The 3.3V power supply to the pico is a filled in area on the front copper layer. Difficult to see on the picture, but it's the red hatching is the limits. However, you made me notice that the connection between U3 and D1 is rather thin. Guess I should make  all power tracks thicker and I guess I could add some 100nF caps as you suggest. Also there is a ground plane, again the boundary is shown by the green hatched line.

Comment: @SteveSh So I want back and checked my code. I had configured GPIO15/CS as a push pull output.

Comment: @SteveSh I'll definitely try adding 22 ohm source termination - see below

Comment: @Andrew Doble - It looks like the CS output turns on (the fast rise time part of the signal), then goes tri state or open drain.  That's a strange behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A simple series resistor for source termination would likely work fine. On the other hand, what you see on the scope is what the probe sees, and you migh be probing the signal in a way that the scope sees ringing. Likely the RC termination on display side is not needed.
2. If scope sees a peak of overshoot, then that is the maximum voltage it measures. The DC level should be 3.3V.

Comment: I'll have a go adding some 22 ohm source termination. Not sure how to do this with the current PCB so I need to do more thinking.

Comment: Never thought that this could be an artifact of the probe. Do you have any way of checking this? Still confused as to why I get highs of 3.6V though.

Comment: If you are using the basic scope crocodile clip for grounding, and have it far away from high speed signals, the inductance of the ground lead combined with fast slew rate of the edge will show overshoots and ringing, and the scope just gives you the highest peak of the overshoot and ringing, not the stable 3.3V because it is not the maximum voltage. Disconnect the ground lead and use the low inductance ground spring instead.

Comment: Ground spring? I had no idea what you meant so I looked it up. They say you learn something new every day and this is what I learnt today. Even went back to the accesories included with the scope and found a pair! Many thanks for pointing this out. I now need to unsolder all my terminations to see if I really have a problem.